# Is there any synonym for "Ordeal" which has a positive connotation?

Tags: synonyms

The word "Ordeal" as defined by google is "a very unpleasant and prolonged experience".
I need a word that does not have this negative connotation attached to it.

Comment: So you would like a word for "a pleasant prolonged experience"?

Comment: Could it be 'Pleasure'?

Comment: An ordeal, by its very definition, has more than just a negative _connotation_: it is a negative _concept_. Are you asking for a similarly negative concept, but without negative connotations? Or for a positive/neutral concept? Or something else entirely? As it stands now, the question is akin to asking, “Is there a word for ‘pain and suffering’ that is not negative?”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knights went on *quests*, which were prolonged experiences with a purpose.

Odysseus went on the original *odyssey*, which is an *epic* tale.

While *quest*, *odyssey*, and *epic* by necessity include unpleasant experiences (dragons, sirens, monsters), there is a joy in the journey that makes the hero a better person.

Answer (score 0):

Exploit, feat, accomplishment, achievement, triumph.  Your question might generate a "use a thesaurus" comment, but because of the negative connotation attached to ordeal, this question requires a bit more than a straight-out thesaurus look-up.